# How does the retrofit mechanical system work in the rear brake pistons of cars (dual hydraulic + mechanical)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

I discovered recently (when changing the rear brake discs/pads of a car) that the piston cannot be pushed back without setting a rotation to it in the same time.
This is due to the dual system with hydraulic (from brake pedal) and mechanics (cable from the hand brake).

I found out a schema [here](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0557283B1/fr) (in French sorry) but I cannot understand which part are involved in the retrofit mechanism of mechanical part.

[image]

Indeed, my current understanding is that:

- When pressing the brake pedal, the piston (203) is pushed directly from right to left by the hydraulic fluid.
- When using the hand-brake, the part (210) is rotating a little, and it presses the key (21), which makes the endless screw (204) to move from right to left. It slightly pushes the parts 209, then 205 and finally the piston 203.

The patent is indicating that the endless screw (204) is auto-blocking.
However, I lack a clear representation of the internals in my mind and I cannot figure out how the part 209 moves progressively to the left, in function of the discs/pads getting used
Particularly, I got stuck with these questions:

1. Is it when the key 204 is moving to the left, or does the 209 turns and remains on the left when the 204 goes back right?
2. Does the piston actually turns when getting out via the the mechanical system, or is the rotation only necessary when resetting the piston manually in a maintenance context?
3. How does the retrofit mechanism actually works internally? Which part are rotating and when?

Comment: Depends on the caliper, some need rotating, others don't. Need to know what you are dealing with before you start working on them, and have the correct tools to rotate the pistons as they can be damaged.

Comment: makes me wonder what guarantees rotation direction for all those turns of the screw.  wrong direction and it would pull the nut right?